# DnD how to disable draggable for a specific component inside of the Draggable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, mui-datatable

I have a MUI Row object in a table, where every Row is draggable.
Inside the Row I have a  object that users can drag the slider left/right. I need to disable the draggable behavior for the slider inside the Row object.

Comment: Found a hacky but brilliant solution here: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1810